# typescript Pick versus direct property reference

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know there's Pick feature in typescript, like so

```
type Article = {
  title: string;
  body: string;
  image: string;
}

type ArticlePreview = Pick<Article, 'title'>
```

but actually you can access the property

```
type ArticleTitle = Article['title']
```

what's the advantage of using Pick? I see the second option is more simple and straight forward.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys

Answer (score 3):

It computes a different type, the two types have different usage (**ArticlePreview** vs **ArticleTitle**).

- ArticlePreview: we compute a type subset of the Article type ;
- ArticleTitle: we retrieve the type of the title property from the Article type.

```js
type ArticlePreview = Pick<Article, 'title'>;
// equivalent to:
type ArticlePreview = { title: string };
// or to:
type ArticlePreview = { title: Article['title'] };
// You could pick more properties using union inside the generic
type ArticlePreview2 = Pick<Article, 'title' | 'image'>

// While

type ArticleTitle = Article['title']
// is equivalent to:
type ArticleTitle = string
```

Comment: Totally correct. Also worth mentioning is that you can extract more than one key when using `Pick`.

Comment: so we should never use Article['title'] at all? I think I've seen it somewhere, maybe the one who wrote it did a mistake?

Comment: I edited my answer : it's perfectly fine to use both of them depending on what you do (`Pick` it's just a shorter way to write the third example in the snippet).